# controller.isGrounded не работает в юнити, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, unity3d

написал код для передвижения персонажа в unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Добавляем ссылку на компонент CharacterController в инспектор
    [SerializeField] CharacterController controller;
    //Добавляем ссылку на переменную speed (скорость игрока) в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] float speed = 5f;
    //Создаем переменную гравитации для падения
    [SerializeField] float gravity = 50;
    //Создаем переменную для силы прыжка
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce = 40;

    //Создаем переменную для направления движения игрока
    private Vector3 direction;


    void Update()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (controller.isGrounded) //проверяем что мы на земле
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                speed = 10f;
            }
            else
            {
                speed = 5f;
            }
            direction = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);

            direction = transform.TransformDirection(direction) * speed;

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
            {
                direction.y = jumpForce;
            }


        }


        direction.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

В другом проекте работал, а сейчас выдаёт ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что делать пожалуйста

Comment: Вы добавили к объекту RigidBody и BoxColider?

Comment: @Deprom это по идее не должно никак влиять на ошибки компиляции.